# crypto.js:562 return binding.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback);

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following error :

```
crypto.js:562
    return binding.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback);
                   ^

TypeError: Not a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:562:20)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2 (crypto.js:548:10)
    at pbkdf2 (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GroupWrites/node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js:56:14)
    at InternalFieldObject.ondone (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GroupWrites/node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js:105:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It was working fine before I implemented a confirm password feature. My form looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Create Your Account</h1>
    <div style="width: 20%; margin: 25px auto;">
        <form action="/register" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="hermioneGranger">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="hermioneGranger@hogwarts.edu">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="gryffindor3" autocomplete="new-password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input id="confirm_password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="gryffindor3" autocomplete="new-password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
                <button id="button" class="btn btn-lg">Create</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Confirm Password Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var password = document.getElementById("password")
  , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword(){
  if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
  } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword; 
</script>
```

And my user schema looks like this :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    subscriptions: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Story"
      }
  ]
})


UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

Please help. Cannot figure this one out. I found out about something called bcrypt and tried to require it in my app.js and get something working but that would not solve my issues. I believe it has something to do with the confirm password script, because before I added it I was making accounts just fine.

Comment: `id=confirm_password`, but `name=password` which creates a duplicate.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov YES! You made my day :) I was really hoping it was a silly mistake like that.